# Что такое "цельнoe словосочетание со значением совместности"?

Tags: пунктуация, управление, сказуемые

Как известно, сказуемое ставится во мн. ч. при подлежащем, представленным цельным словосочетанием со значением совместности, типа *А с Б* (сидели на трубе). Судя по тому, что я нашел (см. ниже) под определение "цельнoe словосочетание со значением совместности" попадает только пара с предлогом *с*. **Значит, словосочетание** *А вкупе с Б* **таковым не является и требует при себе сказуемое в ед.ч.?**

Примечание 1. Некоторые источники (например, третий в моих примерах) еще делят словосочетания со значением совместности на цельные (употребляются со сказуемым во мн. ч.) и свободные (употребляются со сказуемым в ед. ч.). Пример "Элен вместе с Наташей опять вошла в гос­тиную" (Л. Толстой) дается как пример *свободного* словосочетания  именно для того, чтобы подчеркнуть, что в случае типа *А вместе с Б* сказуемое ставится в ед. ч.

Примечание 2. По поводу *А и Б сидели на трубе*. Здесь А и Б - однородные пoдлежащие, с ними и так все ясно, речь идет о более сложных случаях (когда словосочетание выступает в роли одного подлежащего)

Есть еще немало случаев, когда сказуемое ставится во мн. ч. (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo), но меня волнуют словосочетания со значением совместности и похожие на них. По-моему, только наличие предлога *с* (А с Б) позволяет ставить сказуемое во мн. ч. Говоря математическим языком, наличие предлога *с* является необходимым, но не достаточным условием (по-моему). Вопрос, прав ли я.

Цитаты.

Словосочетания со значением совместности. Такие словосочетания называют равноправных участников совместного действия. Главное слово — существительное или местоимение в именительном падеже, зависимое — существительное в творительном падеже с предлогом «с» (https://grammatika-rus.ru/glavnaya/sintaksicheskij-razbor/razbor-slovosochetaniya/)

Одним из видов цельных словосочетаний с общим значением совместности являются сочетания существительных или местоимений, объединенных предлогом с: мать с сыном (http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/tselnyie-slovosochetaniya-68307.html)

Словосочетания со значением СОВМЕСТНОСТИ. Такие словосочетания называют равноправных участников совместного действия). Главное слово — существительное или местоимение в именительном падеже, зависимое — существительное в творительном падеже с предлогом С: брат с сестрой, Коля с товарищем, мы с приятелем (http://lik-bez.com/board/sintaksis/slovosochetanie/45)

Comment: В сети среди примеров к этому определению иногда встречается цитата: "Элен вместе с Наташей опять вошла в гос­тиную" (Л. Толстой). Надёжного первоисточника найти не могу, но не сами же все они это придумали?

Comment: Да, этот пример можно найти в последней из Ваших ссылок.

Comment: Но в этом примере сказуемое стоит в ед.ч!!! То есть это обратный пример: подлежащим является только Элен.

Answer (score 2):

Пример с предлогом "с" по предлагаемому источниками определению "цельным" не является ("значения совместности" не гарантирует). Такая принадлежность опровергается тем, что совместность действия (или равноправность) зависит от контеста, в частности от глагола, определяющего "равноправность":

> Мать с сыном завтракали.
>
> Мать с сыном не церемонилась.

А поскольку А с Б не уравниваются в делах своих и статусе одним только предлогом, они даже "сидеть на трубе" могут по-разному:

> А с Б на плече сидел на трубе и гладил его по шёрстке.

Сложнее развести контекстом совместность действий тех, кто что-то делает "вкупе" или "сообща с".  "Вкупе" - ещё как-то можно. напр. для неодушевлённых и явно неравных сущностей:

> Заказанная карта памяти вкупе с адаптером для старой модели Sony
>   пришла по почте.

Ну а Наташа, равноправная с Элен во многих отношениях, могла быть "менее равной" тем, что, в отличие от Элен, входила в гостиную не "снова", хотя и "вместе".

Comment: Говоря математическим языком, наличие предлога *с* является необходимым, но не достаточным условием (по-моему). Вопрос, прав ли я. Поясните, пожалуйста, считаете ли Вы при некоторых условиях возможным сказать: "Элен вместе с Наташей вошли..."

Comment: В большинстве случаев они "вошли бы" - вместе или порознь (если об этом добавлено: в книгу рекордов Гиннесса - каждая в своей номинации).

Answer (score 2):

> **Значит, словосочетание** *А вкупе с Б* **таковым не является и требует при себе сказуемое в ед.ч.?**

Нет, **не требует.** Лучше употребить какой-нибудь менее *требовательный* глагол.

Розенталь в "Справочнике по правописанию и литературной правке" (М., 1967) писал так:

> При наличии в конструкции слов *вместе, совместно* **чаще**
>   употребляется форма единственного числа сказуемого...

Слово *чаще* отнюдь не говорит о том, что форма множественного числа сказуемого недопустима.

См. примеры со множ. числом:

*Несколько дней назад Санька **вместе с** Лешей Пороховым **сделали** врезку в трубопроводе.*

*Тиф **вместе с** голодом и холодом **сделали** свое черное дело…*

*…Енукидзе **вместе с** комендантом Кремля и командующим Московским военным округом **собирались** арестовать товарища Сталина.*