# Кто или что сидели на трубе?

Tags: одушевленность

> А и Б - сидели на трубе. А - упала, Б - пропала, что (кто) осталось(ся) на трубе?

Затянулся спор: если рассматривать как взрослые, то А и Б - это неодушевленные буквы, а если включить воображение - то буквы оживают в персонажей. Так как правильно называть эти, на самом деле - 3 буквы: А, И, Б?

Похожие вопросы:
[Что такое "цельнoe словосочетание со значением совместности"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435668/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BDoe-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

Comment: Всех вас видал в гробу!"
он забрался в отчаянии на трубу,
ну жена, естественно, вслед за ним...
Проза жизни порою весьма груба —
сцены, ревность, развод, труба...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**А и Б  сидели на трубе. А — упала, Б — пропала, кто остался на трубе?**

Казалось бы, нет никакого сомнения, что персонажи представлены как одушевленные и надо писать ***кто***. Тем не менее люди без воображения, формально подходящие к языку, пишут ***что*** (такие варианты встречаются). Поэтому их надо убедить.

Возьмем толковый словарь и посмотрим значения слова ***сидеть***. Глагол многозначный, но иногда он употребляется по отношению к неодушевленным предметам, например:  В ноге сидит осколок (о старом ранении). Глянь, какой боровичок под сосной сидит (растёт). Гвоздь крепко сидит. Пробка сидит плотно.

**Но вот на трубе неодушевленный предмет явно сидеть не может, поэтому буквы здесь — с точки зрения семантики — одушевленные персонажи.**

В то же время в сказках с неодушевленными предметами в качестве героев **грамматически они все равно считаться неодушевленными**. Например, в сказке "Соломинка, уголек и боб" мы читаем:

А боб...смеялся так сильно, что в конце концов лопнул. Тут бы ему и конец настал, но, к счастью, подвернулся странствующий портной. Он достал иглу и нитки и **сшил лопнувший боб** (не боба).

Answer (score 1):

Персонажи, на мой взгляд. Ибо кто ещё бы мог сидеть на трубе? Если даже допустить, что некая (заводская) труба была украшена надписью ("АБ"? "АИБ"?), то буквы бы на ней не "сидели", а "висели" или ещё бы были как-нибудь по-иному.
Хотя мне нравится другой вариант:

```
А и Б купили дом. А уехал за границу, Б чихнул и лёг в больницу. Кто остался в доме том?
```

А теперь по-другому:

```
А, И, Б купили дом. А уехал за границу, Б чихнул, И лёг в больницу. Кто остался в доме том?
```